# pgppol2 sends write to both master and slave

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, pgpool

I have in issue with pgpool2 and cannot figure out why!!!! my setup is as follows:
singe pgpool to do LB for me
master slave postgress
The issue is as follows, when i send read queries via the pgpool everything is fine, load get distributed between and master and salve.
but when im doing a query that writes to the database the pgpool again uses both slave and master and it yeilds error on queries sent to slave.
I have installed 96 on centos.

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - pgpool Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'
                                   # Host name or IP address to listen on:
                                   # '*' for all, '' for no TCP/IP connections
                                   # (change requires restart)
port = 5432
                                   # Port number
                                   # (change requires restart)
socket_dir = '/tmp'
                                   # Unix domain socket path
                                   # The Debian package defaults to
                                   # /var/run/postgresql
                                   # (change requires restart)


# - pgpool Communication Manager Connection Settings -

pcp_listen_addresses = '*'
                                   # Host name or IP address for pcp process to listen on:
                                   # '*' for all, '' for no TCP/IP connections
                                   # (change requires restart)
pcp_port = 9898
                                   # Port number for pcp
                                   # (change requires restart)
pcp_socket_dir = '/tmp'
                                   # Unix domain socket path for pcp
                                   # The Debian package defaults to
                                   # /var/run/postgresql
                                   # (change requires restart)
listen_backlog_multiplier = 2
                                   # Set the backlog parameter of listen(2) to
                                   # num_init_children * listen_backlog_multiplier.
                                   # (change requires restart)
serialize_accept = off
                                   # whether to serialize accept() call to avoid thundering herd problem
                                   # (change requires restart)

# - Backend Connection Settings -

backend_hostname0 = 'pgdb1'
                                   # Host name or IP address to connect to for backend 0
backend_port0 = 5432
                                   # Port number for backend 0
backend_weight0 = 1
                                   # Weight for backend 0 (only in load balancing mode)
backend_data_directory0 = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data'
                                   # Data directory for backend 0
backend_flag0 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
                                   # Controls various backend behavior
                                   # ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER or DISALLOW_TO_FAILOVER
backend_hostname1 = 'pgdb2'
backend_port1 = 5432
backend_weight1 = 1
backend_data_directory1 = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data'
backend_flag1 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'

# - Authentication -

enable_pool_hba = on
                                   # Use pool_hba.conf for client authentication
pool_passwd = 'pool_passwd'
                                   # File name of pool_passwd for md5 authentication.
                                   # "" disables pool_passwd.
                                   # (change requires restart)
authentication_timeout = 60
                                   # Delay in seconds to complete client authentication
                                   # 0 means no timeout.

# - SSL Connections -

ssl = off
                                   # Enable SSL support
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_key = './server.key'
                                   # Path to the SSL private key file
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_cert = './server.cert'
                                   # Path to the SSL public certificate file
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ca_cert = ''
                                   # Path to a single PEM format file
                                   # containing CA root certificate(s)
                                   # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ca_cert_dir = ''
                                   # Directory containing CA root certificate(s)
                                   # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# POOLS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Concurrent session and pool size -

num_init_children = 32
                                   # Number of concurrent sessions allowed
                                   # (change requires restart)
max_pool = 4
                                   # Number of connection pool caches per connection
                                   # (change requires restart)

# - Life time -

child_life_time = 300
                                   # Pool exits after being idle for this many seconds
child_max_connections = 0
                                   # Pool exits after receiving that many connections
                                   # 0 means no exit
connection_life_time = 0
                                   # Connection to backend closes after being idle for this many seconds
                                   # 0 means no close
client_idle_limit = 0
                                   # Client is disconnected after being idle for that many seconds
                                   # (even inside an explicit transactions!)
                                   # 0 means no disconnection


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOGS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to log -

log_destination = 'stderr'
                                   # Where to log
                                   # Valid values are combinations of stderr,
                                   # and syslog. Default to stderr.

# - What to log -

log_line_prefix = '%t: pid %p: '   # printf-style string to output at beginning of each log line.

log_connections = off
                                   # Log connections
log_hostname = off
                                   # Hostname will be shown in ps status
                                   # and in logs if connections are logged
log_statement = off
                                   # Log all statements
log_per_node_statement = off
                                   # Log all statements
                                   # with node and backend informations
log_standby_delay = 'if_over_threshold'
                                   # Log standby delay
                                   # Valid values are combinations of always,
                                   # if_over_threshold, none

# - Syslog specific -

syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
                                   # Syslog local facility. Default to LOCAL0
syslog_ident = 'pgpool'
                                   # Syslog program identification string
                                   # Default to 'pgpool'

# - Debug -

debug_level = 0
                                   # Debug message verbosity level
                                   # 0 means no message, 1 or more mean verbose

#log_error_verbosity = default          # terse, default, or verbose messages

#client_min_messages = notice           # values in order of decreasing detail:
                                        #   debug5
                                        #   debug4
                                        #   debug3
                                        #   debug2
                                        #   debug1
                                        #   log
                                        #   notice
                                        #   warning
                                        #   error

#log_min_messages = warning             # values in order of decreasing detail:
                                        #   debug5
                                        #   debug4
                                        #   debug3
                                        #   debug2
                                        #   debug1
                                        #   info
                                        #   notice
                                        #   warning
                                        #   error
                                        #   log
                                        #   fatal
                                        #   panic

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FILE LOCATIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

pid_file_name = '/var/run/pgpool-II-95/pgpool.pid'
                                   # PID file name
                                   # (change requires restart)
logdir = '/tmp'
                                   # Directory of pgPool status file
                                   # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTION POOLING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

connection_cache = on
                                   # Activate connection pools
                                   # (change requires restart)

                                   # Semicolon separated list of queries
                                   # to be issued at the end of a session
                                   # The default is for 8.3 and later
reset_query_list = 'ABORT; DISCARD ALL'
                                   # The following one is for 8.2 and before
#reset_query_list = 'ABORT; RESET ALL; SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION DEFAULT'


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REPLICATION MODE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

replication_mode = off
                                   # Activate replication mode
                                   # (change requires restart)
replicate_select = off
                                   # Replicate SELECT statements
                                   # when in replication mode
                                   # replicate_select is higher priority than
                                   # load_balance_mode.

insert_lock = off
                                   # Automatically locks a dummy row or a table
                                   # with INSERT statements to keep SERIAL data
                                   # consistency
                                   # Without SERIAL, no lock will be issued
lobj_lock_table = ''
                                   # When rewriting lo_creat command in
                                   # replication mode, specify table name to
                                   # lock

# - Degenerate handling -

replication_stop_on_mismatch = off
                                   # On disagreement with the packet kind
                                   # sent from backend, degenerate the node
                                   # which is most likely "minority"
                                   # If off, just force to exit this session

failover_if_affected_tuples_mismatch = off
                                   # On disagreement with the number of affected
                                   # tuples in UPDATE/DELETE queries, then
                                   # degenerate the node which is most likely
                                   # "minority".
                                   # If off, just abort the transaction to
                                   # keep the consistency


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOAD BALANCING MODE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

load_balance_mode = on
                                   # Activate load balancing mode
                                   # (change requires restart)
ignore_leading_white_space = on
                                   # Ignore leading white spaces of each query
white_function_list = ''
                                   # Comma separated list of function names
                                   # that don't write to database
                                   # Regexp are accepted
black_function_list = 'currval,lastval,nextval,setval'
                                   # Comma separated list of function names
                                   # that write to database
                                   # Regexp are accepted

database_redirect_preference_list = ''
                                   # comma separated list of pairs of database and node id.
                                   # example: postgres:primary,mydb[0-4]:1,mydb[5-9]:2'
                                   # valid for streaming replicaton mode only.

app_name_redirect_preference_list = ''
                                   # comma separated list of pairs of app name and node id.
                                   # example: 'psql:primary,myapp[0-4]:1,myapp[5-9]:standby'
                                   # valid for streaming replicaton mode only.
allow_sql_comments = off
                                   # if on, ignore SQL comments when judging if load balance or
                                   # query cache is possible.
                                   # If off, SQL comments effectively prevent the judgment
                                   # (pre 3.4 behavior).

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MASTER/SLAVE MODE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

master_slave_mode = on
                                   # Activate master/slave mode
                                   # (change requires restart)
master_slave_sub_mode = 'stream'
                                   # Master/slave sub mode
                                   # Valid values are combinations slony or
                                   # stream. Default is slony.
                                   # (change requires restart)

# - Streaming -

sr_check_period = 10
                                   # Streaming replication check period
                                   # Disabled (0) by default
sr_check_user = 'pgpool'
                                   # Streaming replication check user
                                   # This is neccessary even if you disable streaming
                                   # replication delay check by sr_check_period = 0
sr_check_password = 'pool'
                                   # Password for streaming replication check user
sr_check_database = 'postgres'
                                   # Database name for streaming replication check
delay_threshold = 10000000
                                   # Threshold before not dispatching query to standby node
                                   # Unit is in bytes
                                   # Disabled (0) by default

# - Special commands -

follow_master_command = ''
                                   # Executes this command after master failover
                                   # Special values:
                                   #   %d = node id
                                   #   %h = host name
                                   #   %p = port number
                                   #   %D = database cluster path
                                   #   %m = new master node id
                                   #   %H = hostname of the new master node
                                   #   %M = old master node id
                                   #   %P = old primary node id
                                   #   %r = new master port number
                                   #   %R = new master database cluster path
                                   #   %% = '%' character

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HEALTH CHECK
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

health_check_period = 10
                                   # Health check period
                                   # Disabled (0) by default
health_check_timeout = 20
                                   # Health check timeout
                                   # 0 means no timeout
health_check_user = 'pgpool'
                                   # Health check user
health_check_password = 'pool'
                                   # Password for health check user
health_check_database = ''
                                   # Database name for health check. If '', tries 'postgres' frist, 
health_check_max_retries = 0
                                   # Maximum number of times to retry a failed health check before giving up.
health_check_retry_delay = 1
                                   # Amount of time to wait (in seconds) between retries.
connect_timeout = 10000
                                   # Timeout value in milliseconds before giving up to connect to backend.
                                   # Default is 10000 ms (10 second). Flaky network user may want to increase
                                   # the value. 0 means no timeout.
                                   # Note that this value is not only used for health check,
                                   # but also for ordinary conection to backend.

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FAILOVER AND FAILBACK
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

failover_command = '/etc/pgpool-II-95/failover.sh %d %H'
                                   # Executes this command at failover
                                   # Special values:
                                   #   %d = node id
                                   #   %h = host name
                                   #   %p = port number
                                   #   %D = database cluster path
                                   #   %m = new master node id
                                   #   %H = hostname of the new master node
                                   #   %M = old master node id
                                   #   %P = old primary node id
                                   #   %r = new master port number
                                   #   %R = new master database cluster path
                                   #   %% = '%' character
failback_command = ''
                                   # Executes this command at failback.
                                   # Special values:
                                   #   %d = node id
                                   #   %h = host name
                                   #   %p = port number
                                   #   %D = database cluster path
                                   #   %m = new master node id
                                   #   %H = hostname of the new master node
                                   #   %M = old master node id
                                   #   %P = old primary node id
                                   #   %r = new master port number
                                   #   %R = new master database cluster path
                                   #   %% = '%' character

fail_over_on_backend_error = on
                                   # Initiates failover when reading/writing to the
                                   # backend communication socket fails
                                   # If set to off, pgpool will report an
                                   # error and disconnect the session.

search_primary_node_timeout = 300
                                   # Timeout in seconds to search for the
                                   # primary node when a failover occurs.
                                   # 0 means no timeout, keep searching
                                   # for a primary node forever.

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ONLINE RECOVERY
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

recovery_user = 'pgpool'
                                   # Online recovery user
recovery_password = 'pool'
                                   # Online recovery password
recovery_1st_stage_command = ''
                                   # Executes a command in first stage
recovery_2nd_stage_command = ''
                                   # Executes a command in second stage
recovery_timeout = 90
                                   # Timeout in seconds to wait for the
                                   # recovering node's postmaster to start up
                                   # 0 means no wait
client_idle_limit_in_recovery = 0
                                   # Client is disconnected after being idle
                                   # for that many seconds in the second stage
                                   # of online recovery
                                   # 0 means no disconnection
                                   # -1 means immediate disconnection


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WATCHDOG
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Enabling -

use_watchdog = off
                                    # Activates watchdog
                                    # (change requires restart)

# -Connection to up stream servers -

trusted_servers = ''
                                    # trusted server list which are used
                                    # to confirm network connection
                                    # (hostA,hostB,hostC,...)
                                    # (change requires restart)
ping_path = '/bin'
                                    # ping command path
                                    # (change requires restart)

# - Watchdog communication Settings -

wd_hostname = ''
                                    # Host name or IP address of this watchdog
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_port = 9000
                                    # port number for watchdog service
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_priority = 1
                                    # priority of this watchdog in leader election
                                    # (change requires restart)

wd_authkey = ''
                                    # Authentication key for watchdog communication
                                    # (change requires restart)

wd_ipc_socket_dir = '/tmp'
                                    # Unix domain socket path for watchdog IPC socket
                                    # The Debian package defaults to
                                    # /var/run/postgresql
                                    # (change requires restart)


# - Virtual IP control Setting -

delegate_IP = ''
                                    # delegate IP address
                                    # If this is empty, virtual IP never bring up. 
                                    # (change requires restart)
if_cmd_path = '/sbin'
                                    # path to the directory where if_up/down_cmd exists 
                                    # (change requires restart)
if_up_cmd = 'ip addr add $_IP_$/24 dev eth0 label eth0:0'
                                    # startup delegate IP command
                                    # (change requires restart)
if_down_cmd = 'ip addr del $_IP_$/24 dev eth0'
                                    # shutdown delegate IP command
                                    # (change requires restart)
arping_path = '/usr/sbin'
                                    # arping command path
                                    # (change requires restart)
arping_cmd = 'arping -U $_IP_$ -w 1'
                                    # arping command
                                    # (change requires restart)

# - Behaivor on escalation Setting -

clear_memqcache_on_escalation = on
                                    # Clear all the query cache on shared memory
                                    # when standby pgpool escalate to active pgpool
                                    # (= virtual IP holder).
                                    # This should be off if client connects to pgpool
```

---------+----------+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------

0       | pgdb1    | 5432 | 2      | 0.500000  | primary | 10581

1       | pgdb2    | 5432 | 2      | 0.500000  | standby | 2351

Role      | Name  | Upstream | Connection String

----------+-------|----------|-------------------------------------

standby | pgdb2 |          | host=pgdb2 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr

- master  | pgdb1 |          | host=pgdb1 user=repmgr dbname=repmgr

--

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: PreventCommandIfReadOnly and  cannot execute SELECT in a read-only transaction